# Webpack ES6 modules multiple class app organization

Tags: javascript, class, webpack, es6-modules, es6-class

I'm building an app with webpack for the first time and i'm trying to wrap my head around organizing class files. I'm having trouble getting the code to work. I'm still new to ES6 and such, so my code below is probably very wrong but i'm not sure its my approach/concept or its my syntax.

entry is `index.js` and I also have these files

```js
import App from './js/app.js';
import User from './js/user.js';
import Guest from './js/guest.js';

const app = new App();
const user = new User();
const guest = new Guest();

$(document).ready(function () {
    app.DatabaseStore.senddata();
    console.log( user.getall() );
});
```

`src/js/app.js` the main global method/variable class

```js
import CookieStore from './cookie.js';
import DatabaseStore from './database.js';

export default class App {
    constructor() {
        this.cookieStore = new CookieStore();
        this.databaseStore = new DatabaseStore();
    }
    gettime() {
        return 'time';
    }
}
```

`src/js/user.js` methods that are for `users`

```js
import App from './app.js';

export default class User extends App {
    constructor() {
        this.mydata = App.cookieStore.getData();
        console.log(this.mydata );
    }
    getall() {
        return ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
    }
}
```

`src/js/guest.js` methods that are for `guests`

```js
import App from './app.js';

export default class Guest extends App {
    constructor() {
        this.mydata = App.cookieStore.getData();
    }
}
```

`src/js/cookie.js` cookie manipulating methods

```js
export default class CookieStore {
    constructor() {}
    mydata() {return 'foo';}
}
```

`src/js/database.js` firebase methods

```js
export default class DatabaseStore {
    constructor() {}
    senddata() {
        this.mydata = App.cookieStore.getData();
    }
```

Comment: What is exactly the problem?

Comment: for example calling `App.cookieStore.getData()` in `User` class yields method not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access instance property statically. You need to create an instance of `App` class before trying to access `cookieStore` property. You can create an instance and export it in your app.js to have singleton instance.

```
//in your app.js 
export const app = new  App();
```

in other files

```
import {app} from './js/app.js'

app.cookieStore.getData();
```

Comment: That is perfect, seemed to fix `guest.js` and `user.js`. However when I add `import {app} from './js/app.js'` to `index.js` I can't access `app.databaseStore.senddata()`

Comment: You wrote `app.DatabaseStore.senddata();` instead of `app.databaseStore.senddata();`

Comment: Check these Lines `
$(document).ready(function () {
    app.DatabaseStore.senddata();
    console.log( user.getall() );
});`

Comment: Also, Since you have App instance created in app.js you might want to `import {app} from './js/app.js' ` in your `index.js` instead of doing `var app = new App()` again

Comment: You are correct. I was able to fix that. Yeah I updated the `index.js` so that the class doesn't get called twice.

Comment: one last issue, how can I access `cookieStore` class from within `databaseStore` class?

Comment: In your database constructor in database.js, make cookieStore a dependency `constructor(cookieStore){ this.cookieStore = cookieStore;` then in your app.js `this.databaseStore = new DatabaseStore(this.cookieStore);`

Comment: with that approach I would have to do `this.cookieStore.method`. However inside promises, the scope for `this` is different. Is the only solution to set a local variable outside of the promise `var cookieStore = this.cookieStore` or is there a better solution?

Comment: You can use es6 `=>` function to retain the scope i.e. `new Promise(()=>{...})`